# People API not returning deleted contacts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-people-api

I'm using Google Scripts and People API.  The following code is not returning deleted contacts.  As I understand the People API, deleted contacts should be returned with the metadata deleted as true. Thanks!

```
function getUpdatedContacts() {

  var connections = People.People.Connections.list('people/me', {
      sortOrder: 'LAST_MODIFIED_DESCENDING',
      pageToken: pageToken, // previously declared
      syncToken: syncToken, // previously declared
      pageSize: 1000,
      personFields: 'addresses,biographies,birthdays,calendarUrls,clientData,emailAddresses,events,externalIds,genders,imClients,interests,locales,locations,memberships,metadata,miscKeywords,names,nicknames,occupations,organizations,phoneNumbers,relations,sipAddresses,urls,userDefined'
  })
  return (connections);
}
```

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list, "when the syncToken is specified, resources deleted since the last sync will be returned as a person with PersonMetadata.deleted set to true." It looks like deleted contacts outside of the last sync time (or contacts that have been deleted for a long time) will not be returned when tested on my end.

Comment: Thanks, but I've confirmed they have been deleted since the last syncToken was set.  Contacts which were modified prior to the deleted contact are still being returned.

Comment: Not sure what happened, but deleted contacts are being returned today.  No idea why.  Didn't change anything.